# How do I configure the VSCode Coverage Gutters extension to work with tox?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, tox

I'm using the [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters) extension to show code coverage, but it only works when running `pytest` directly, not when running `pytest` via `tox`. I believe this is because my `cobertura/coverage.xml` file contains references to the copies of the files inside the `.tox` directory, not the actual source files which for me are inside a `src/my_package` directory.

Excerpt from my `coverage.xml` file when run via `tox`:

```xml
    <packages>
        <package name=".tox.py38.lib.python3.8.site-packages.my_package" line-rate="0.6772" branch-rate="0" complexity="0">
            <classes>
                <class name="__init__.py" filename=".tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/my_package/__init__.py" complexity="0" line-rate="1" branch-rate="0">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line number="3" hits="1"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
```

Excerpt from the same file when run via `pytest` (Coverage Gutters works fine with this file):

```xml
    <packages>
        <package name="src.my_package" line-rate="0.6772" branch-rate="0" complexity="0">
            <classes>
                <class name="__init__.py" filename="src/semper_cli/__init__.py" complexity="0" line-rate="1" branch-rate="0">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line number="3" hits="1"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
```

I've been playing around with various configurations in `tox.ini`, taking inspiration from answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70308862/722553), but no matter what I do, my source files show up as "no coverage" in the Coverage Gutters extension and the XML still shows package names like `.tox.py38.lib.python3.8.site-packages.my_package`.

So coverage reporting is working fine, but Coverage Gutters is not displaying any coverage indicators.

Any ideas?

Comment: write a script that does the file path find/replace after running tox and use a compound task if done by a task